# Why do I have to add a Microsoft Teams app to Team twice before it sends conversationUpdate activity

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've been working on a Microsoft Teams app, and have been using the `conversationUpdate` message type that should be triggered whenever the app (or a user) is added to a team to send a welcome message. I am using the `upload a custom app` feature that Microsoft Teams has to upload the app.

For some reason, when I add the app to the team I want it on, the `conversationUpdate` message has never fired for me on the first attempt. No error message or warning of any type. It doesn't work until I go to the team I just added the app to, click the ellipses for the team and go to `manage team`, click apps, and remove the app I just added, then add the app again to the team. Only then do I get the correct `conversationUpdate` message that I can use to send out a welcome message.

I've tested out various bots written by Microsoft in their BotBuilder samples here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs and have gotten the same result as my custom bot. I don't know why this error occurs and if it is isolated to an app uploaded with the `upload a custom app` feature.

Does anybody have insight as to why this is happening and if it happens on the Microsoft Teams App catalog as well?

Comment: Checking on it and will get back to you soon

Comment: Can you please share your bot ID and timestamp?

Comment: 6b8103f6-9ce4-4e41-bda5-f7d876957da0 - Here is the ID of my bot. What timestamp are you referring to? Was there one generated when the bot was created?

Comment: @Mallipriya-MSFT Have you been able to take a look at this?

Comment: I was not able to repro the issue and can you check confirm even with the sample on [proactive messaging](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages) you are facing this issue.

Comment: @Mallipriya-MSFT The sample proactive messaging you asked me to test isn't related to the issue that I'm facing. I can send messages to the bot and receive messages from it as well. The sole issue that I'm facing is that when I upload my custom app and then add it to a team, it doesn't fire off the conversationUpdate as it says it should here [Bot subscribe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet).

Comment: A good sample showing what is going wrong is this: [Teams Conversation Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot) Which is the repo I used to replicate my issue. You'll notice that when adding to a team, you'll get a conversationUpdate solely between the bot and user. It does not send a conversationUpdate for adding it to the team even though looking at apps shows it as added. Let me know if you need me to send a video example

Comment: Hi @trevash, I got it working for Teams Conversation Bot. Can we discuss this over a call? Could you please write to us at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out what the issue was. It would work the very first time I added the bot to a Team, but when I removed it, I was removing it from the Apps -> Built for your org only and not also removing it from the individual Team I had added it to. For some reason, when I did it this way, the first time I added the bot back in it would not trigger the conversationUpdate activity. Presumably because it thought that it was added to that Team still. Not sure exactly why, but that's what is happening.